# How to set one ObservableCollection to another ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, observablecollection

Basically, I want to know if I can do this with two ObservableCollections:

```
oldList = newList;
```

I have two lists that get populated throughtout my app, and each time they get populated, I want the 'new' values to become the 'old' values, and then get a new set of values to put in the 'new' list.

is it that easy? Any other way to do this without iterating over the whole newList every time?

**EDIT: This is how the new list is being populated. Basically, I just want the contents of the newList to be put into the oldList.**

```
                foreach (object obj in ts.GetVariables())
            {
                if ((obj.ToString() != "_SMSTSReserved2") || (obj.ToString() != "OSDJoinPassword") || (obj.ToString() != "OSDLocalAdminPassword"))
                {
                    TSVar var = new TSVar();
                    var.TSVarName = obj.ToString();
                    var.TSVarValue = ts[obj.ToString()];
                    newList.Add(var);
                }
            }
            oldList.Clear();
            foreach (TSVar var in newList)
            {
                oldList.Add(var);
            }
```

Comment: Can you show the code on how they new values are being populated?

Comment: Have you looked at the CollectionChanged event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the extension method listed below, what you are trying to do becomes a one liner:

```
oldList.Replace(newList);
```

I would create an Extension Method for ObservableCollection like this:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensionMethods
    {
        public static void Replace<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> old, ObservableCollection<T> @new)
        {
            old.Clear();
            foreach (var item in @new)
            {
                old.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ObservableCollectionExtensionMethodsTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ReplaceTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var old = new ObservableCollection<string> { "1"};
            var @new = new ObservableCollection<string> {"2"};

            // Act
            old.Replace(@new);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("2", old.First());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you may be looking for? This will add everything that was in newList to your oldList.

```
ObservableCollection<YourType> oldList = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(newList);
newList.clear();
//put new stuff in your list here.
```

Comment: With this solution, make sure you implement some kind of change (like INotifyPropertyChanged) notification for OldList (I assume you are using WPF), otherwise you will still be bound to the (now no longer referenced [in this object] ObservableCollection).